# How to call correctly run few class (intents)?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm beginner in Java Android developing. I'm using Eclipse SDK 3.6.1 version. I'm trying to do this thing: in first class (layout - main.xml) is button "hello", it calls new class (layout - second.xml), in this class are button "hello2", it calss new class. I can't do this cause when I push  first button "hello" I getting this messages "The aplication (xxxx) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". How to resolve this problem. I think problem is in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.kodinis_raktas"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".veiksmas"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".second" >
    <intent-filter>   
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>                 
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".lock"></activity> 
    <intent-filter>
    </intent-filter>   
</application>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your error. That will give you more information.

I would recommend getting rid of the `<intent-filter>` elements from `.second` and `.lock`, since you are not using them. If your error is coming from trying to start `.second`, the existence of your category-only `<intent-filter>` may well prevent that activity from being started.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience with android I think you need to add this line after `activity android:name=".second"`

`android:label="@string/app_name">`